# I keep getting the error: TypeError: integer argument expected, got float in Python 3.6.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python version 3.6.5, downloaded from Python.org. While programming, I keep getting the error `TypeError: integer argument expected, got float`. I am  using Python version 3.6.5, win 32 bit. Here is my complete code yet (to be worked on still):

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
sky_blue = (0,150,225)
green = (0,255,0)

displayWidth = 800

displayHeight = 600
#Final :- pygame.display.set_mode((1365, 1050))
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((displayWidth,displayHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption('Super Mario')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

crashed = False

timeOut = False

Quit = False

#50,75
marioStanding = pygame.image.load('Super_Mario_Standing.jpg')
marioStanding = pygame.transform.scale(marioStanding, (displayWidth/40,displayHeight/8))

def Stand(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(marioStanding,(x,y))

x = (displayWidth * 0.45)
y = (displayHeight * 0.8)

while not crashed and not timeOut and not Quit:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Quit = True

    print (event)

    gameDisplay.fill(sky_blue)
    Stand(x,y)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(24)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

I was not getting any error before removing the height and width as `50,75`, and replacing it with `displayWidth/40, displayHeight/8`, so I'm guessing that it has something to do with that. Here is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Super_Mario_Python3.6\Billionth_Pygame_Test.py", line 28, in <module>
    marioStanding = pygame.transform.scale(marioStanding, (displayWidth/40,displayHeight/8))
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your example could be reduced to about 4 lines of code. This makes the question clearer and improves the likelihood of good answer. See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to python 3 floating point division. Here:

```
pygame.transform.scale(marioStanding, (displayWidth/40,displayHeight/8))
```

your divisions, even if made between integers, create a tuple of *float* elements.

```
>>> 200/40
5.0
```

Use *integer division* to keep them as integers (this wasn't the case in python 2) so the `scale` function accepts them as arguments.

```
>>> 200//40
5
```

like this:

```
pygame.transform.scale(marioStanding, (displayWidth//40,displayHeight//8))
```

Note: it also works in python 2.